# How to highlight text as desired using regular expressions to be used in Splunk?

Tags: splunk

I have the following regex which displays the following output:
[image]
Desired green text.But when added to Splunk, shows exact same output as previous regex.

What I want is to make it such that the exact highlighted green text gets highlighted in Splunk for field extraction.

Previous regex:
[image]
The highlighted green text got misaligned.

What I suspect is that I have to make the '< 37 > 1' highlighted in blue too, so that Splunk will extract the green text correctly. As this regex was done by another user when I asked in Splunk, the user did not add '< 37 > 1' in his sample regex which affected the alignment when I added it to Splunk. I've tried different variations to highlight the '< 37 > 1' but to no avail.

Some examples of my variations:

(?:[^\s][^\s][^\s]+\s+){2}(?P[^\s]+(?:\s\w+)?)\s\d+\s+<

(?:[^\s][^\s]+\s+){2}(?P[^\s]+(?:\s\w+\s)?)\s\d+\s+<

(?:[^\s][^\s]+\s+){2}(?P[^\s]+(?:\s\w+\w)?)\s\d+\s+<

(?:[^\s][^\s]+\s+){2}(?P[^\s]+(?:\s\w+\w\w)?)\s\d+\s+<

\<(?:[^\s][^\s]+\s+){2}(?P[^\s]+(?:\s\w+)?)\s\d+\s+<

(?:[^\s][^\s]+\s+\s){2}(?P[^\s]+(?:\s\w+)?)\s\d+\s+<

Link of the regex:
https://regex101.com/r/biHi9a/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know Splunk doesn't use color when parsing text, right?
If I understand your question and examples correctly, you want to extract the text between "E876876876" and the first digit.  Assuming "E876876876" is not a fixed string, this regex should extract "auth" and "SECURE AUDIT".

```
":\d\dZ\s\w+\s(?P<field1>[^\d]+)"
```

Comment: but when I am extracting new fields with regular expression Splunk highlights out the extracted field in green. Thanks so much your regex worked. @RichG